# mysql connection state in visual studio 2012 c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I have this application to retrieve data from `MySql` database and I do not need to open connection to connect to database how is this possible? Usually you need to add like `connection.Open()` and `connection.Close()`. Am i missing something here? I use Visual studio 2012 and ADO.NET 4.0

Code:

```
public partial class Filter1 : Form
{
    public Filter1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Filter1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=;database=;uid=;password=;");
         MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
         DataSet DS = new Dataset();

         MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
         mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);
         mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS.Tables[0]);
         ViewG.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: The MySql connector classes that you are using are doing it for you internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to **manually** open and close the connection because `mySqlDataAdapter.Fill()` will do it **automatically** for you. See the docs: [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The first paragraph under Remarks reads:

> The IDbConnection object associated with the select command must be
>   valid, but it does not need to be open. If the IDbConnection is closed
>   before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If
>   the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

Comment: So after `mySqlDataAdapter.Fill()` it closes automatically?

Comment: Yes. See my edit. If it was closed before Fill(), it will open and close it. If it was originally open, it will leave it open.